# Transformar la propiedad de un objeto con map en el lenguaje Kotlin para android

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo una list de  objetos de Personas en kotlin y necesito transformar la propiedad nombre a mayusculas.

Revisando la documentacion de kotiln, encontre que se llaman: Operaciones sobre colecciones: operaciones de filtrado.

Entonces estoy usando la funcion map, para esto, pero el problema es que la funcion de extencion map, devuelve la lista solo solo con la propiedad nombre y desaparece la propiedad edad.

```
data class Persona(val nombre:String, val edad: Int)

val personas = listOf(
    Persona("Juan", 74),
    Persona("Alejandro", 25),
    Persona("Juan", 25),
    Persona("Laura", 51)
)

fun main(){
    val resultado2 = personas
        .asSequence()
        .mapIndexed{idx, value -> value.nombre.toUpperCase() }
        .toList()
    println("map= $resultado2")
}
```

Mostrar impresion:

```
transformacion= [JUAN, ALEJANDRO, JUAN, LAURA]
```

List original:

```
[Persona(nombre=Juan, edad=74), Persona(nombre=Alejandro, edad=25), Persona(nombre=Juan, edad=25), Persona(nombre=Laura, edad=51)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás indicándole al lambda que retorne nada más el nombre en mayúsculas. Si quieres que retorne la Persona con el nombre modificado tienes que crear un nuevo objeto con esa propiedad modificada porque `nombre` es inmutable. Tampoco hace falta invocar `asSequence` y la función `map` la puedes invocar así tal cual, no hace falta el índice.

```
val resultado2 = personas
        .map{
            it.copy(nombre = it.nombre.toUpperCase())
        }
        .toList()
```

Comment: `toList()` tampoco hace falta. Sólo para completar la respuesta, agregaría que a partir de kotlin 1.5 debería usar `uppercase()` en vez de `toUpperCase()`. Este último usa el idioma del dispositivo y en algunos idiomas produce un resultado que no es el esperado.

Comment: @Glenn Sandoval,  Muchas  gracias por tu valiosa opinión, desconocía esa manera de hacerlo.